# Object reference not set to an instance of an object - highlighting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, nullreferenceexception

I used to do this previously and it worked, but now it shows error, any suggesstion?
What does Object reference not set to an instance of an object mean?

```
@foreach (var item in Model) 
{
    int daysLeft = (item.Membership.PaidDate - DateTime.Today).Days;
    string style = daysLeft <= 7 ? "background-color:Red" : null;
        <tr style="@style">
```

Comment: may be `item.Membership` or `item.Membership.PaidDate` is null. Check it, if it is not null...

Comment: Almost all cases of `NullReferenceException` are the same. Please see "[What is a NullReferenceException in .NET?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4660142/what-is-a-nullreferenceexception-in-net)" for some hints.

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems `item.Membership is NULL`

**Object reference not set to an instance of object means** the variable you are trying to use to get access to an object doesnt have a reference to the object.For example

```
Employee e;
```

If without writing `e= new Employee()`, if i try to get/execute property/method of `Employee` type then it is an error because `e` is not referring to any instance of this type.